# npm start command I am getting syntaxerror: use of const in strict mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

- when I run npm start command I am getting the below error
- I followed the below steps in the link
  https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md
- can you tell me how to fix it
- providing error below

xxx-nameKumar--MacBook-Pro:MyApp xxx-name$ npm start

```
> @ start /Users/xxx-name/Desktop/FrontEnd/MyApp
> babel-node tools/run start

/Users/xxx-name/Desktop/FrontEnd/MyApp/tools/run.js:20
  const task = typeof fn.default === 'undefined' ? fn : fn.default;
  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at loader (/Users/xxx-name/Desktop/FrontEnd/MyApp/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:126:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/xxx-name/Desktop/FrontEnd/MyApp/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at /Users/xxx-name/Desktop/FrontEnd/MyApp/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:161:27
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx-name/Desktop/FrontEnd/MyApp/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:162:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ start: `babel-node tools/run start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script 'babel-node tools/run start'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     babel-node tools/run start
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/xxx-name/Desktop/FrontEnd/MyApp/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: You only need to execute `npm start`.

Comment: @gnerkus I executed npm start but still I am getting the error...why xxx-nameKumar--MacBook-Pro:MyApp xxx-name$ npm start

Comment: gnerkus, he doing exactly that....texi, thats not it, read the error:SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.

Comment: @Omarjmh I just noticed. Thanks for pointing it out. @texi rv, what version of Node do you have installed? You can check with this `node -v`.

Comment: @gnerkus hey its v0.12.0

Comment: @texirv did my answer work?

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

Do you have 'use strict' in your code?

What version of node do you have?

The const and let are part of ES6 and are not enabled by default in Node.js 0.10 or 0.12.

Comment: like what specifically?

Comment: the question isnt about how to update node. And since when do you designate your version of node in the package.json? If you're going to leave comments at least take the time to make them meaningful

Comment: The required version is usually specified in the `'engines'` section of the `package.json`. https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/package.json

Comment: how about instead of pointing to ONE package.json as an anecdote you go to the npm docs and read about engines: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json
you dont set your version in there, you tell node what version your app needs

Comment: The problem is that nodejs is out of date

Answer (score 1):

Update nodejs. Const is a new feature. The version you have (0.12.0) is outdated. The link says you need 5.0 or newer. Download and install 5.9.1 (not 4.4.1) form https://nodejs.org/en/. Then try again.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail? How can he update his version of Node? Why is his version of Node outdated? Could it be the result of the version specified in the module's `package.json`?

Answer (score -2):

You can try to update your npm by typing

> sudo Npm install -g npm

Comment: The problem is that nodejs is out of date